# My question is about XML data in SQL Server - need to understand this SQL function below

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Here is a function which my application is using to set a data of a table (grid) as it is in a normal header fields. For example if I choose YES in a header every data in that grid and row if it is NO it will change into YES. But i am not able to understand that how they are taking the data from the live web form as XML. How can i get the XML string for this.

```
create function dbo.fCore_Var0 (@s xml) 
returns decimal(17, 2)
as 
begin
    declare @iCurrentRow int
    declare @iTotalRowCount int
    declare @iTotalYesCount int

    select @iCurrentRow=@s.value('(/Fields/Header/CurrentRow)[1]', 'int') -- returns curr row index

    if @iCurrentRow >= 0
    begin
        declare @tbPrincipleTags as table (iIdd int identity(0,1),iProductId int,iCompletionStatus int)

        insert into @tbPrincipleTags(iProductId ,iCompletionStatus)  
            select 
                pd.value('iProductId[1]', 'int'), 
                pd.value('iCompletionStatus[1]', 'int') 
            from 
                @s.nodes('/Fields/BodyData/AllRows') as x(Rec) -- returns all products
            cross apply 
                @s.nodes('/Fields/BodyData/AllRows/BodyRow') as i(pd)

        delete from @tbPrincipleTags where iProductId=0

        select @iTotalRowCount = count(*) 
        from @tbPrincipleTags

        select @iTotalYesCount = count(*) 
        from @tbPrincipleTags 
        where iCompletionStatus = 1

        if @iTotalYesCount = @iTotalRowCount
            return 'YES'
        else 
            return 'NO'
    end

    return 'NO'
end
go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title tells me, that you want to understand this function. But the question in the text is

> How can i get the XML string for this.

Well, to answer this first: This was best at the sender. But you can start the *"SQL-Server-Profiler"* and monitor the queries flying by. In the profiler the arguments will show up.

To understand your function:

The XML seems to contain several rows. A temporary table containing `iProductID` and `iCompletionStatus` is filled from these rows.

All rows with `iProductId=0` are pushed aside.

The `YES` will be returned only in case, where the count of rows and the count of completed rows is the same. In other words: You get a `YES` when all rows are completed.

Hope this helps...